# Factory-girl factory using reserved word

Tags: factory-bot

I have a model named "Case" and another model named "CaseUpdateLog" which has a belongs to association in its model.

```
class CaseUpdateLog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :case
end
```

If case is not added to the case_update_log Factory then I get an error:

```
* case_update_log - Validation failed: Case must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid).
```

If I add "case" to the case_update_log Factory get error: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, because case here gets interpreted as the kickoff of a switch statement.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :case_update_log do
    case
  end
end
```

I have tried

```
factory :case, :aliases => [:a_case] do
```

in the case Factory and then used a_case in the case_update_log Factory but it still gives me error: * case_update_log - undefined method `a_case=' for # Did you mean?  case= (NoMethodError).  Please advise if you have a solution.  Thank you.

Comment: actually this might work - association :case, factory: :case

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#method-name--reserved-word-attributes